# Find the longest common sequence of two strings in Rust

Tags: beginner, algorithm, strings, rust

I've attempted to solve a small coding challenge [I found online](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=10WnvBk9sZc) as a nice way to begin learning Rust. The largest challenge I feel going in with Rust is how working with strings is so fundamentally different from any other programming language I've used before. The challenge was this:

> **Write a function that takes two strings, s1 and s2
>   and returns the longest common sequence of s1 and s2:**
>
> "ABAZDC", "BACBAD" => "ABAD"
>   "AGGTAB", "GXTKAYB" => "GTAB"
>   "aaaa", "aa" => "aa"
>   "ABBA", "ABJABA" => "ABBA"

The challenge seemed simple but the way I understood how I one could iterate though Rust strings proved to be very difficult. With numerous copies of iterators made and copies of `String`s being made back and forth I am aware that this program is in its most naive form.

I wonder if collecting the string's characters into a vector would've been a better approach. I really want to find a more efficient method of solving this problem with Rust that'll be more comparable to C++ in terms of performance.

```
#[macro_use]
extern crate criterion;

use criterion::Criterion;

fn longest_con_seq(s1:&String, s2:&String) -> String {

    let mut max: Option<String> = None; // Holds value of string with maximum length
    let mut current = String::new(); // String container to hold current longest value
    let mut s1_iter = s1.chars().peekable(); // Peekable iterator for string s1
    let mut s2_iter = s2.chars(); //Iterator for string s2
    let mut s2_prev_pos = s2_iter.clone(); // Iterator that holds position of previous location of first iterator
    let mut s1_prev_pos = s1_iter.clone(); // Peekable iterator used to make sure all possible combinations are located.

    loop {  
        let s1_char = s1_iter.next(); // Get character in s1
        if current.len() == 0 // If no consequtive string found yet store location of iterator
        {
            s1_prev_pos = s1_iter.clone()
        }
        match s1_char{
            Some(s1_char)=>
            {   
                loop{    
                    match s2_iter.next()
                    {
                        Some(s2_char) if s1_char == s2_char => {
                            current.push(s1_char);
                            s2_prev_pos = s2_iter.clone();
                            break;
                        },
                        Some(_)=>continue,
                        None=>{
                            s2_iter = s2_prev_pos.clone();
                            break;
                        },
                    }
                }
            },
            None=>{
                match s1_prev_pos.peek()
                {
                    Some(_) => {
                        match max{
                            Some(_) => {
                                let max_str = max.clone();
                                let max_str = max_str.unwrap();
                                if max_str.len() < current.len(){
                                    max = Some(current.clone());
                                }
                                current.clear();
                            },
                            None => {
                                max = Some(current.clone());
                                current.clear();
                            },
                        }
                        s1_iter = s1_prev_pos.clone();
                        s2_iter = s2.chars();
                    },
                    None => break,
                }
            },
        }
    }
    if let Some(_) = max {
        return max.unwrap();
    } else {
        return String::from("");
    }
}
fn criterion_benchmark(c: &mut Criterion) {
    let s1 = "GXTKAYB".to_owned();
    let s2 = "AGGTAB".to_owned();
    c.bench_function("Benchmark", move |b| b.iter(|| longest_con_seq(&s1, &s2)));
}
criterion_group!(benches, criterion_benchmark);
criterion_main!(benches);
```

## C++ comparison

I wrote a C++ version of the code that manipulates the strings through their indices. I though it would outperform the Rust code but it wasn't so.

```cpp
#include <benchmark/benchmark.h>
#include <string>

std::string longest_con_seq(std::string &s1, std::string &s2)
{
    std::string max = "", current = "";
    size_t s2_old_idx = 0, s1_old_idx = 0;
    bool first_iter = true;
    for(size_t s1_idx = 0; s1_idx < s1.length(); ++s1_idx)
    {   
        if(first_iter)
            s1_old_idx = s1_idx;

        first_iter = false;
        for(size_t s2_idx = s2_old_idx; s2_idx < s2.length(); ++s2_idx)
        {
            if(s1[s1_idx] == s2[s2_idx])
            {
                s2_old_idx = s2_idx + 1;
                current += s1[s1_idx];
                break;
            }
        }

        if(s1_idx == s1.length()-1 && s1_old_idx != s1.length()-1)
        {
            s1_idx = s1_old_idx;
            s2_old_idx = 0;
            if(max.length() == 0 || max.length() < current.length())
            {
                max = current;
            }
            current.clear();
            first_iter = true;
        }
        else if( s1_old_idx == s1.length()-1 )
        {
            break;
        }
    }
    return max;
}


static void BM_LongestConSeq(benchmark::State& state) {
    std::string s1 = "GXTKAYB", s2 = "AGGTAB";
    for (auto _ : state)
    {
        longest_con_seq(s1,s2);
    }
}
// Register the function as a benchmark
BENCHMARK(BM_LongestConSeq);


BENCHMARK_MAIN();
```

### Results

#### Rust

```
**time:**   [96.755 ns **97.291 ns** 98.031 ns]   
**change:** [-2.8521% _-1.4304%_ -0.1568%] (p = 0.04 < 0.05)  
                        Change within noise threshold.  
_Found 12 outliers among 100 measurements (12.00%)_  
5 (5.00%) high mild  
7 (7.00%) high severe
```

## C++

```
Benchmark
----------
Time: **152 ns**  
CPU: **152 ns**  
Iterations: **4471469**
```

I really don't know how to interpret the results, I used Google Benchmark for the C++ code and Criterion for the Rust code. It seems to look like the Rust code has outperformed the C++ code, but maybe I'm wrong.

Comment: Sure, I'll write c++ version and benchmark both but its pretty clear with the ability to directly access indices with minimal to no copying of iterators the c++ solution would be much more efficient.

Comment: @BiggySmallRyeda I think you underestimate LLVM

Comment: From experience with both C++ and Rust, performance is generally comparable, as long as you use equivalent operations. In terms of iterators specifically, C++ iterators compose badly, which generally give an edge to Rust if you start piling "filtering" iterators... but that's not very common.

Comment: @MatthieuM. I added the edits you and the others recommended. I don't understand the results of the benchmark very well. Also, can someone judge my rust approach to the problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Run [Rustfmt](https://github.com/rust-lang-nursery/rustfmt), a tool for automatically formatting Rust code to the community-accepted style.
2. Run [Clippy](https://github.com/rust-lang-nursery/rust-clippy), a tool for finding common mistakes that may not be compilation errors but are unlikely to be what the programmer intended.
3. Don't accept a `&String` — [Why is it discouraged to accept a reference to a String (&String) or Vec (&Vec) as a function argument?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/40006219/155423)
4. Don't use explicit `return` keywords at the end of blocks.
5. Instead of

   ```
   if let Some(_) = max {
       max.unwrap()
   ```

   bind the variable:

   ```
   if let Some(x) = max {
       x
   ```
6. Your whole last conditional can be simplified to `max.unwrap_or_default()`.
7. Add some automated tests.

   ```
   #[test]
   fn example_1() {
       assert_eq!(longest_con_seq("ABAZDC", "BACBAD"), "ABAD");
   }

   #[test]
   fn example_2() {
       assert_eq!(longest_con_seq("AGGTAB", "GXTKAYB"), "GTAB");
   }

   #[test]
   fn example_3() {
       assert_eq!(longest_con_seq("aaaa", "aa"), "aa");
   }

   #[test]
   fn example_4() {
       assert_eq!(longest_con_seq("ABBA", "ABJABA"), "ABBA");
   }
   ```
8. As before, don't match on `Some` and then `unwrap`, bind the variable. We can also avoid the clone by matching on a reference:

   ```
   match max {
       Some(_) => {
           let max_str = max.clone();
           let max_str = max_str.unwrap();
   ```

   ```
   match &max {
       Some(max_str) => {
   ```
9. `current.clear()` is used in both match arms; extract it.
10. `max = Some(current.clone())` is the same; extract it and use a boolean.

    ```
    let do_it = match &max {
        Some(max_str) => {
            max_str.len() < current.len()
        }
        None => {
            true
        }
    };

    if do_it {
        max = Some(current.clone());
    }
    ```
11. This construct can be replaced by `as_ref` and `map_or`:

    ```
    if max.as_ref().map_or(true, |s| s.len() < current.len()) {
        max = Some(current.clone());
    }
    ```

#### End result

```
#[macro_use]
extern crate criterion;

use criterion::Criterion;

fn longest_con_seq(s1: &str, s2: &str) -> String {
    let mut max: Option<String> = None; // Holds value of string with maximum length
    let mut current = String::new(); // String container to hold current longest value
    let mut s1_iter = s1.chars().peekable(); // Peekable iterator for string s1
    let mut s2_iter = s2.chars(); //Iterator for string s2
    let mut s2_prev_pos = s2_iter.clone(); // Iterator that holds position of previous location of first iterator
    let mut s1_prev_pos = s1_iter.clone(); // Peekable iterator used to make sure all possible combinations are located.

    loop {
        let s1_char = s1_iter.next(); // Get character in s1

        if current.is_empty() {
            // If no consecutive string found yet store location of iterator
            s1_prev_pos = s1_iter.clone()
        }

        match s1_char {
            Some(s1_char) => loop {
                match s2_iter.next() {
                    Some(s2_char) if s1_char == s2_char => {
                        current.push(s1_char);
                        s2_prev_pos = s2_iter.clone();
                        break;
                    }
                    Some(_) => continue,
                    None => {
                        s2_iter = s2_prev_pos.clone();
                        break;
                    }
                }
            },
            None => match s1_prev_pos.peek() {
                Some(_) => {
                    if max.as_ref().map_or(true, |s| s.len() < current.len()) {
                        max = Some(current.clone());
                    }
                    current.clear();

                    s1_iter = s1_prev_pos.clone();
                    s2_iter = s2.chars();
                }
                None => break,
            },
        }
    }

    max.unwrap_or_default()
}

fn criterion_benchmark(c: &mut Criterion) {
    let s1 = "GXTKAYB";
    let s2 = "AGGTAB";
    c.bench_function("Benchmark", move |b| b.iter(|| longest_con_seq(s1, s2)));
}

criterion_group!(benches, criterion_benchmark);
criterion_main!(benches);

#[test]
fn example_1() {
    assert_eq!(longest_con_seq("ABAZDC", "BACBAD"), "ABAD");
}

#[test]
fn example_2() {
    assert_eq!(longest_con_seq("AGGTAB", "GXTKAYB"), "GTAB");
}

#[test]
fn example_3() {
    assert_eq!(longest_con_seq("aaaa", "aa"), "aa");
}

#[test]
fn example_4() {
    assert_eq!(longest_con_seq("ABBA", "ABJABA"), "ABBA");
}
```

> With numerous copies of iterators made and copies of Strings being made

Copies of iterators are *generally* going to be extremely lightweight. In many cases, they are equivalent to a pointer and and offset.

Cloning a `String` is slightly less ideal, but that may just be a restriction of the algorithm.